# SSRS 2008: Passing Parameters to linked report

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have a report table with all the combinations of dimensions as generated by the parameters set by the user. Each row contains 1 combination and a link to another report with charts. How do I pass that combination of parameters/dimensions to that other report?

In the row, I have a textbox Action which has a "Go to report" hyperlink. In the main report. I see an option "Use these parameters to run the report" which I fill out with the similarly named parameters on both reports.

On the linked report, the user should not have to pick options from that set of parameters again. Setting the report parameters to internal, hidden with blank prompt (a single space), visible with blank prompt (a single space), and putting a (Null) default value still gives: "The report parameter  is read-only and cannot be modified. (rsReadOnlyReportParameter)"

What gives? How should the parameters be configured on either side so the combination of parameters are passed to the linked report?

Answer (score 4):

If it is truly a [linked report](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190170.aspx), then you should be able to hide the parameter in the linked report properties.

If it's a [drill through report](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627584.aspx) (more likely), then just set the [parameter to hidden in designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337234.aspx). Internal means it is not exposed at all:

> Setting the Hidden and Internal
>   options provides different levels of
>   visibility. You can hide the parameter
>   on the parameter input area of the
>   published report, yet set values for
>   it on a **report URL** [*My text: this is what drill through does*] or in a
>   subscription definition. If you set a
>   parameter to Internal, it is not
>   exposed in any way except in the
>   report definition.

Answer (score 1):

The real solution to the real problem probably lies somewhere else, but just recreating the report item from scratch instead of using the converted (from SSRS 2005 to SSRS 2008) report item solved the problem described above. The drillthrough report should have the parameter hidden.